# Align the content in SimplePanel in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

Anyone know how to put something in the center of SimplePanel or at least to arrange it somehow.

with HorizontalPanel adn VerticalPanel i could use setHorizontalAlignment() /setVerticalAlignment() but i am not able to find anything useful for SimplePanel.

I know that SimplePanel can have only one widget, but i m required to use it.

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Horizontal/Vertical panel.
Add widget with required alignment.
Add this panel to the SimplePanel.

You can also probably achieve it by tweaking the CSS instead of having an extra panel

Answer (score 2):

If you use UIBinder this should work

```
 <ui:style>
  .container {
     width:100%;
 }
 .content {
     width:200px;
     margin: 0 auto;
 }
</ui:style>
<g:SimplePanel addStyleNames="{style.container}">
    <g:HTMLPanel addStyleNames="{style.content}">
     <!-- CONTENT -->
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</g:SimplePanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, but i don't use UIBinder.

Comment: @adgfs - Then you should read up about it, and start using it. It isn't just a fancy tool you know.